# I want to increase the width of Quick Launch

Tags: windows, windows-vista, windows-explorer, quicklaunch

I want to increase the width of Quick Launch but can't figure out a way to do so.

I'm using Windows Vista Home Premium SP2 32-bit 
[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Right click on the taskbar and uncheck the option to lock it. Then use the drag handles that become visible to resize the Quick Launch panel.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Unlock the task bar (by right clicking and unchecking) then drag the top part up.